# Creating Tags and filtering according to them in django

Tags: django, python-3.6, django-filter, django-tagging

I'm creating a blog application to share interview experiences and i would like to filter the blog posts based on year, company of interview and job roles etc..
how do i take the above parameters as tags and when clicked on a certain tag, have to show all posts on that just like how stackoverflow does?
My model looks like this

```
class experience(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    job_role=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    year=models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use taggit .. it has all the features you require..

```
 django-taggit.readthedocs.io
```